# Rellenar Input mediante un select

Tags: c#, sql, mvc

Estoy trabajando con MVC 5 y base datos de SqlServer, lenguaje C#.
tengo un formulario de ventas, en dicho formulario tengo un select que me muestra un listado de los productos. Lo que deseo hacer que al seleccionar algun producto en el select,me traiga datos del producto tales como precio, stock, etc. y me los muestre en sus respectivos input.
Me funciona pero solo mostrandome en Id en un Input. pero deseo tambien que me mustre mas datos de ese producto en otros input.
Gracias.

Comment: Bueno, ya lo resolviste.. agarra ese id, y busca los datos en la db....

Comment: Hola Otto, bienvenido, tu pregunta se parece mucho a "tengo este ejercicio, háganlo", este tipo de preguntas, no suelen ser bien recibidas, te sugiero que la edites, y muestres que has intentado, para saber que formas parte de la resolución de tu problema,  mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.